# Why is data bytes size different when serialized with JSONSerialization

Tags: json, swift, serialization, uint8t

Why is data serialized using JSONSerialization differ from the data serialized with the extension below?

```
let uint8Array: [UInt8] = [123, 234, 255]
let data1 = uint8Array.data // 3bytes
let data2 = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: uint8Array) // 13 bytes

extension Data {
    var bytes: [UInt8] {
        return [UInt8](self)
    }
}

extension Array where Element == UInt8 {
    var data: Data {
        return Data(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: JSONSerialization uses UTF8 and also adds other characters for its protocols, like "," and brackets, it converts it into a "String". So the output as String of data2 is "[123,234,255]", which is a String of length 13. While data1, is just 123 value inside a byte, 234 inside a byte, and 255 inside a byte as "rawValue".

Answer (score 0):

JSON, and so the JSONSerialization will transform an object (here an array of Int), into `Data` according to some rules (like adding `"["`, `"]"`, `","` in our cases, in others input values and options, it can add if necessary `":"`, `"{"`, `"}"`, "\n"`, etc) and using the UTF8 (or kind of UTF16, but I'll skip this part for understanding, see [this part in WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Character_encoding)) encoding.

So in fact, for `123` value, it will be `1` into UTF8 encoding, then `2`, then `3`, so just for one number, it's 3 bytes.
So you see that for your 3 Int numbers, it will be 9 bytes, then, we need to add the `"["`, `"]"`, and the two commas to separate them: `","`, which makes 9 + 2 + 2 = 13 bytes.

To illustrates:

Let's add:

```
extension Data {
    func hexRepresentation(separator: String) -> String {
        map { String(format: "%02hhX", $0) }.joined(separator: separator)
    }
    func intRepresentation(separator: String) -> String {
        map { String(format: "%d", $0) }.joined(separator: separator)
    }
}
```

And use it to see what are the values inside data1 & data2:

```
print(data1.hexRepresentation(separator: "-"))
print(data1.intRepresentation(separator: "-"))
print(data2.hexRepresentation(separator: "-"))
print(data2.intRepresentation(separator: "-"))
```

```
$>7B-EA-FF
$>123-234-255
$>5B-31-32-33-2C-32-33-34-2C-32-35-35-5D
$>91-49-50-51-44-50-51-52-44-50-53-53-93
```

I let you chose as you prefers Int or hex raw value interpretations.

We see that using the first method, we get 3 bytes, with the initial values of your array.

But for the JSON one, we can split it as such:

```
$>91 -> [
$>49-50-51 -> 1, 2 & 3
$>44 -> ,
$>50-51-52 -> 2, 3, 4
$>44 -> ,
$>50-53-53 -> 2, 5, 5
$>93 -> ]
```

You can check on any UTF8 table (like https://www.utf8-chartable.de, etc), but `91` that for `[`, 49 it's for `1`, etc.